# How to prevent text from being echoed over netcat (nc) when reading it with bash's read -s?

Tags: bash, netcat

I have an authentication implemented in a bash script.
A user enters his password through this line of code:

```
read -s password
```

When entering the password over `nc` the password gets echoed like the `-s` option would not have been used.
This doesn't happen when running the script normally.

Is there an alternative to `nc` or an option for it that supports the `-s` option of bash's read function?

I tried this:

```
stty -echo
read -s password
stty echo
```

but the password still gets displayed.

Comment: When you use netcat, there's no terminal involved on the remote system. You need to turn off echoing in the client, not the server.

Comment: `stty`, `read -s`, etc all reconfigure the TTY. You can't do that when all you have is a pipe that sends and receives characters and no device you can run `ioctl()`s against, and a pipe is all `nc` is ever promised to provide; for TTY support you need a protocol designed to forward things a TTY can do and emulate a TTY by creating a PTY on the remote end; the classic/pre-security/unencrypted protocol for that is `telnet`. Netcat can do many things, but terminal emulation is something it has never promised.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried the same thing with telnet and it also displays the password when typing. Also telnet is not great because it sends a `\r` after the password string which `nc` does not do.